# Convert URLs to Hyperlinks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my database with around 3000 records. One of the columns in this table contains data including URLs. I wish to convert these URLs into Hyperlinks so that when the content is rendered onto a web page, it is an anchor element linking to the URL.

For example the content may be like:

```
Lorem ipsum http://domain.com dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras consequat nisl vitae leo pellentesque tempus et id nunc. Vestibulum varius facilisis fringilla
```

And I want to change it to:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href='http://domain.com' target='_blank'>http://domain.com</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras consequat nisl vitae leo pellentesque tempus et id nunc. Vestibulum varius facilisis fringilla
```

I've tried doing:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Content=REPLACE(Content, "http://domain.com", "<a href='http://domain.com' target='_blank'>http://domain.com</a>")
```

But this only works for that one exact URL, whereas I need it to work for any URL starting with `http://`

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Comment: Sure you want to do that? Having a URL value is much more useful then having a html link element. Can you not wrap it with html before you render it?

Comment: @musefan I would agree, but this system uses a Telerik editor to allow users to add hyperlinks themselves, so I would prefer the existing data to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a programming language of your choice, SELECT all entries, manipulate them with a regex that replaces the URLs in each row and UPDATE each row.

If you want to use SQL Server directly, you could try implementing a CLR function on your DB server. The following link explains how to do it:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx

Then you'd use a pattern to match the URLs, like

```
^http://([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)([\.][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)+([/][a-zA-Z0-9\~\(\)_\-]*)+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9\(\)_\-]+)*$
```

(that regex works, but is probably not complete)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You will have to parse your string and split of the parts you need. Have a look at the t-sql character functions. Mainly "charindex" and "substring"